Content restriction based on contacts in subscribed list
I have a form with activecampaign on my website, and when they fill it out, the list subscribers receive an email with an access URL to a page with content. So far everything is correct. The idea is that people who are subscribed to the list and click on the url that I have in the email and can directly see the content of the page (without logging in or anything like that), but if they copy They /paste/share the link, if the person they share it with is not on the list they cannot see the content.
The website is WordPress.
Is there any way to do it?
I have spoken with hostinger and activecampaign support and they have referred me to this forum.
Thanks in advance.
I have tried pluggins (like restric content etc) and it hasn't worked for me.
I've tried PHP code on my server (supposedly to identify the activecampaign ID and the email url with token ID) and it doesn't work. I've been trying to find the solution for more than a week.
P.S: I have a private membership with memberpress but I don't want those who access the email content to have to log in.
This is the code of the generate-enlace.php file that I placed on my server:
<?php
function generate_unique_token($length = 32) {
    return bin2hex(random_bytes($length));
}

function store_token($email, $token) {
    // Conexión a la base de datos
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "tu_usuario";
    $password = "tu_contraseña";
    $dbname = "tu_base_de_datos";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Conexión fallida: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $expiration = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 day'));
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tokens (email, token, expiration) VALUES ('$email', '$token', '$expiration')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    $conn->close();
}

$email = $_GET['email'];
$token = generate_unique_token();
if (store_token($email, $token)) {
    echo "https:/web.es/gift/?token=$token";
} else {
    echo "Error al generar el enlace.";
}
?>

this code verifies the token on the “Gift” page and redirects unauthorized users
<?php
// Conexión a la base de datos
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "tu_usuario";
$password = "tu_contraseña";
$dbname = "tu_base_de_datos";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Conexión fallida: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Obtén el token de la URL
$token = $_GET['token'];

// Verifica si el token es válido y no ha expirado
$sql = "SELECT email FROM tokens WHERE token='$token' AND expiration > NOW()";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // El token es válido, muestra el contenido
    echo "Contenido restringido";
} else {
    // El token no es válido o ha expirado, redirige a la página de no autorizado
    header("Location: https://web.es/usuario-no-autorizado/");
    exit();
}

$conn->close();
?>

The link placed in the email is this
https://web.com/generar-enlace.php?email=%EMAIL%.
I update post with example of the codes

what is technically possible is an url with a key and this key allows only one use. then if the user send the url to someone else, no other person can use it. to do that you can, e.g., use this function : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_meta/. if you need more help, edit your question to show us the code you tried.

updated, thanks
